Informador por Defecto Jira
estoy tratando de automatizar tickets de soporte en Jira, son 5 proyectos distintos y por lo tanto son 5 clientes distintos que enviaran soportes. Solo me permitieron utilizar un correo el cual es Support, ya lo tengo configurado para que cualquier cliente pueda enviar un ticket y Jira lo interprete mediante una palabra clave y lo coloque en su respectivo proyecto. Lo que pasa es que en el ticket del proyecto creado, se guarda con mi usuario y no con el del cliente que crea el ticket, alguien sabe como solucionar esto?

Si el informador por defecto lo quito, esto resultara en otro problema y es que ya ahora los clientes envian los tickets pero jira no los guardara

Alguna idea de como puedo guardar el informador por defecto vacio para que no me guarde los tickets bajo mi usuario? Y que si me cree los tickets si lo dejo en vacio?

Jira tiene un soporte al usuario y una documentación que recomiendo utilizar. Aquí no damos soporte a aplicaciones de terceros por lo general. Ellos lo hicieron, y saben exactamente cómo usarlo
